# i have a problem with my project

Tags: spring-mvc

i have a problem, i generated a build jar of other project, because i want to use its methods, then i imported this library in my project without never problem, well i used a MVC, in the controller´s name is java.java and it is here when i imported the new library and i used, then i run project,  this is a error message,

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMap' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'welcome' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'catalogFacadeTarget' while setting bean property 'catalogFacadeImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'catalogFacadeTarget' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/read/biff/BiffException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'welcome' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'catalogFacadeTarget' while setting bean property 'catalogFacadeImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'catalogFacadeTarget' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/read/biff/BiffException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'catalogFacadeTarget' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/read/biff/BiffException
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/read/biff/BiffException

Comment: this is the image of my project: http://www.mediafire.com/imageview.php?quickkey=73mcaa918jocxer&thumb=4

Comment: protip: two spaces after a line to linebreak.

Answer (score 0):

It says, class jxl.read.biff.BiffException is not found. You need to add the jar file that contains jxl.read.biff.BiffException class to your projects classpath.

You can obtain the jar file from [findjar.com](http://www.findjar.com/class/jxl/read/biff/BiffException.html)